# how can i change the drop down menu direction from ltr to rtl

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu

I've download this JQuery menu style from the following link:
http://apycom.com/menus/15-dim-gray.html

but I don't know how to change the direction of the drop down menu from ltr to rtl since the list is in Arabic.I'm not so familiar with JQuery.

So could any one help me to solve this issue?

Comment: Isn't it just a case of CSS styles? `direction:rtl`

Comment: as the source code isn't accessable for free, i don't think anybody will be able to help you easily (if they don't buy the menu). The best thing you could probably do is contact apycom directly and ask for their support.

Comment: Just inspect the element (dropdown) on your page, find a particular attribute (class, id) and set the CSS rule. That's it.

Comment: no.It's free.Before buy, there's free download!!

Comment: MelanciaUK but where to put direction:rtl??????!!!!

Comment: How do you want change the direction. Put up a fiddle. Don't understand whether you want to change the direction of text or the whole menu. Please put up a fiddle

Comment: download the code from this mediaFire link:http://www.mediafire.com/download/dweb7durs7e6ec0/apycom.com-15-dim-gray+%281%29.zip

Comment: i want to change the direction of the sub item so the arrow is to left not to right like this menu:http://rtl-this.com/sites/default/files/demos/superfish/index.html#horizontal

Comment: you should look at their css, change every left to right and every right to left, I've always do this, replace all left to leftl then replace all right to left and then again replace all leftl to right then make sure you have put direction:rtl in css in top content. if there's any image hook to css you must rotate the image horizontally or you get ugly page! It's really easy for someone who knows css and it is very hard for a beginner!

Comment: could any one give me a website to download free drop down menu in jquery with animation  ?????!!!!